# Unexpected keys (gender, dob) detected in parameter array on auth_email_signup_user function

Tags: moodle

I am trying to add registration to the android app that uses standard Moodle endpoints from the server hosted at the Moodle site. So on the postman, I am using the function "auth_email_signup_user" with the fields:

> ```
> firstname:Mteja
> lastname:WaNambari
> email:mteja@gmail.com
> username:mteja
> password:1234pass
> gender:Male
> dob:05/09/2000
> ```

but then I keep getting this responce from postman

```
{
    "exception": "invalid_parameter_exception",
    "errorcode": "invalidparameter",
    "message": "Invalid parameter value detected",
    "debuginfo": "Unexpected keys (gender, dob) detected in parameter array."
}
```

Maybe someone can help me figure this out the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameters for this function can be found in the code at:
https://github.com/moodle/moodle/blob/master/auth/email/classes/external.php#L187

If you look in there you can see that the expected parameters are:

- username
- password
- firstname
- lastname
- email
- city (optional - the VALUE_DEFAULT part indicates this)
- country (optional)
- recaptchachallengehash (optional)
- recaptcharesponse (optional)
- customprofilefields (optional - array)
- redirect (optional)

I'm assuming that 'gender' and 'dob' are custom profile fields that you have defined for your site (because I don't think, off the top of my head, that those are standard fields).

If that is correct, then you will need to send data that looks like this:

```
firstname:Mteja
lastname:WaNambari
email:mteja@gmail.com
username:mteja
password:1234pass
customfields[0][name]:gender
customfields[0][value]:Male
customfields[0][type]:text
customfields[1][name]:dob
customfields[1][value]:05/09/2000
customfields[1][type]:date
```

(I'm afraid I'm guessing a bit at the 'type' field - from the code it appears to be a required field, but at the same time I can't see anywhere that it is actually used. The date format might also need to be a Unix timestamp, not a formatted date - I don't have a Moodle install in front of me right now to see if it works).

Comment: what about when I do get the error: "Missing required parameters: profile_field_Gender,profile_field_DoB" does your answer still applicable?

Comment: I managed to get this working with this parameters

firstname:Mteja
lastname:WaNambari
email:mteja@gmail.com
username:mteja
password:1234pass
customprofilefields[0][name]:profile_field_Gender
customprofilefields[0][value]:Male
customprofilefields[0][type]:text
customprofilefields[1][name]:profile_field_DoB
customprofilefields[1][value]:05/09/2000
customprofilefields[1][type]:date